# Spring boot - How to handle page not found exception using exception handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm making a handler wherein i should be able to redirect the user to login page or customised error page when the user tries to access a non-existing url, i'm using an exception handler to catch the error, but the problem is it doesn't go to the handler, instead it just gives me a white label error page..

here's the code:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public String exception(ResourceNotFoundException e, HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        long now = new Date().getTime();
        long lastAccessed = request.getSession().getLastAccessedTime();
        boolean isNotLoggedIn = (now - lastAccessed) <= 0L;

        if (isNotLoggedIn) {
            return "forward:/login";
        }

        return "forward:/access-forbidden?errorMessage=Page Not found.";
    }
```

Comment: which template engine you are using??

Comment: i'm using thymeleaf

Comment: src/main/resources/templates/error/404.html ,thymeleaf will handle errors automatically without controller.it will render 404 page if it encounter and 404 error automatically

Comment: but i also want to use this handler to redirect the user to login page if the user is not yet logged in..

Answer (score 10):

I think you can try this, at least it worked for me :

1. Add this two properties in the `application.properties` :

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

2. Change the type of the exception from `ResourceNotFoundException` to `NoHandlerFoundException`

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = NoHandlerFoundException.class)
public String exception(NoHandlerFoundException e, ...) {
```

Comment: This was the only way for me to ensure that my custom ControllerAdvice was being triggered by `NoHandlerFoundException ` exception.

Comment: In new version of Spring `spring.resources.add-mappings` was relpaced with `spring.web.resources.add-mappings`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation and extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` in the class handling these exceptions.

Comment: I have `@ControllerAdvice` annotation above my class, but when i try to extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` it gives me a:



public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)}